# Update new with values from a seperate query

Tags: sql-server

I've got this query which returns a list of id's and int values

```
SELECT
Opportunity.opportunityid
,obn.cnt
FROM Opportunity
LEFT JOIN Account
ON Opportunity.AccountId = Account.AccountId
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT
    COUNT(dst) AS cnt
FROM [server].[telecoms].[dbo].[vwOpportunityUpdate]
WHERE dst COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = REPLACE(Account.Telephone1,' ','') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
AND calldate > opportunity.createdon
GROUP BY dst) obn
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,Opportunity.CreatedOn,GETDATE()) < 30
AND obn.cnt IS NOT NULL
```

All I need to do is update a table based on the values in those results

```
UPDATE Opportunity SET callcount = (obn.count from previous query)
WHERE OpportunityId = OpportunityId
```

I'm not sure how to join the two things together.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the results of the first query into a temporary table, then use that table to join on the other table in your update clause.

```
SELECT
Opportunity.opportunityid
,obn.cnt as cnt
INTO #CallCounts
FROM Opportunity
LEFT JOIN Account
ON Opportunity.AccountId = Account.AccountId
OUTER APPLY 
(SELECT
    COUNT(dst) AS cnt
FROM [server].[telecoms].[dbo].[vwOpportunityUpdate]
WHERE dst COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = REPLACE(Account.Telephone1,' ','') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
AND calldate > opportunity.createdon
GROUP BY dst) obn
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,Opportunity.CreatedOn,GETDATE()) < 30
AND obn.cnt IS NOT NULL

UPDATE o
SET callcount = c.cnt
FROM Opportunity o
JOIN #CallCounts c on c.opportunityID = o.opportunityID

DROP TABLE #CallCounts
```